# What happens to cron jobs when the system is down?

Tags: cron

As the title suggests:

What happens to con jobs scheduled for a time when the system is down for any reasons as server maintenance or whatever?

If it is simply not executed: Is there a way to manually execute **all** (or better: **all missed**) cron jobs at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is not executed.

There is a program called Anacron that should better serve your needs

[information about it here](http://anacron.sourceforge.net/)